# MSTest: Grouping of Tests

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mstest

I'm setting up a UnitTest Suite using MSTest for an existing application.

The application supports two different databases (SQLServer and MSAccess), so we want each Unit Test to run against both databases.

I have kind of achieved this functionality with the following class construct

```
namespace SQLServer {
    [TestClass] public class SQLServer : TestCases { }
}
namespace MSAccess {
    [TestClass] public class MSAccess : TestCases { }
}

public abstract partial class TestCases {
    //Tests for Module1
    [TestMethod] public void Module1_Test1() { }

}
public abstract partial class TestCases {
    //Tests for Module2
    [TestMethod] public void Module2_Test1() { }
}
```

This works more or less as expected, but of course it's not very nice because all `TestMethod`s must be in the same class. It also has the downside that two `TestMethod`s for different modules cannot have the same name, making the names of the methods unnecessarily long.

My main problem is however that I lose the grouping of `TestMethod`s by module. The grouping in Test Explorer that I achieve with this is:

```
UnitTestProject (Project name)
  UnitTestProject.SQLServer (Namespace name)
    SQLServer (Class name)
      Module1_Test1 (Function name)
      Module2_Test1
  UnitTestProject.MSAcccess
    MSAccess
      Module1_Test1
      Module2_Test1
```

What I actually want is:

```
UnitTestProject 
  SQLServer
    Module1
      Module1_Test1
    Module2
      Module2_Test1
  MSAccess
    Module1
      Module1_Test1
    Module2
      Module2_Test1
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

[Use the `TestCategory` attribute](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2018/07/organizing-test-cases.aspx) and ensure your tests are grouped by Traits in the Test Explorer window.

Comment: This seems to only group them by Trait. When grouped by Trait, every test exists double in every Trait because they're inherited by the two base classes. It does not give grouping by both, DB-Type and TestCategory